# Direct3D & Assimp Texture is inverted weirdly!

Tags: c#, c++, textures, directx, directx11

I'm working on a rendering engine but even on the first mesh is something wrong.
I use assimp for mesh importing!
In the Assimp Viewer it looks correct:

[image]

And in my software it looks like this:

[image]

Look at the text and you will see it is weirdly mirrored.
I'm using front counter clockwise vertex winding and the texture is flipped on y coordinate - if I don't then it is completely wrong. I already tried disabling front counter clockwise winding but the texture is still inverted!

Does anybody know what else I can try?

Comment: It would really improve your question if instead of posting links of images, you could include the images themselves on your post, so users attempting to answer will not have to visit "unknown" links. It will also make your question more future-proof, as links may get broken, and someone having a similar problem with you in the future might not be able to benefit from this question.

Answer (score 1):

The texture is correct but the model itself is inverted. This is probably at some stage due to changing between right-handed and left-handed co-ordinate systems.

You should try and check which handedness your importer expects, and perhaps change one of the axes to negative values.